# Importing mail messages into Solr (no IMAP)

Tags: email, solr, lucene

How would I go about importing email message text files into Solr without connecting to IMAP? For instance, if I use the API, how should I set it up to index a mail message correctly?

I am new to configuring Solr. I am aware of the MailEntityProcessor, but my application is bespoke and does not use IMAP directly. I would like to import the raw text email message into Solr as they arrive.

Any help will be much appreciated.

Answer (score 0):

Write a program that gathers information from whatever source you need (like your email system), constructs a Solr document, and batches up documents to send to Solr.

Solr comes with a Java client (SolrJ) that is actually part of Solr itself, and many third-party clients have been written for other programming languages.

Comment: Thank you. Once it is received in Solr, will the indexing be automatic for mail messages, i.e. indexing it with separate fields for recipients, subject, content, attachments, etc.? If not, I think this is the heart of my problem. What configuration should be done to achieve this?

Comment: You would have to write a program that handles extracting field info from an email message.

It would be possible to steal some of the code directly from MailEntityProcessor and put it in a SolrJ program -- use the extracted info to create a SolrInputDocument object.  This would not be a trivial task, but most programmers who are experienced with Java could probably handle it.

Alternately, you could use MailEntityProcessor as inspiration for writing something in a language other than Java.